# Why were my sentences corrected like this?

Tags: grammar

B is the original sentences I wrote.
A is the sentences changed by some native speaker.

A:

> We can think below sentences mean the same thing. But, I think, when I watch an action movie, I hear a lot more "get" than "have". So, I think "get" has more active or urgent meaning than "have"

B:

> Even, we can think above two senteces are the same meaning. But I think when I watch action movie, I hear a lot more " get" than " have". So, I think "get" has more active or urgent meaning than "have".

Comment: "A" still has errors, I query the knowledge of this "native speaker". Where do these sentences come from? Maybe you should just rewrite this and ask if your sentences are incorrect and why.

Comment: I don't have the ability to correct sentence B.Becuz, in my eyes, it seems right.I don't know what is wrong and right anyway.

Comment: Do definately native speakers think sentence B is somewhat written by foreigners?

Comment: @fdfl324 I have lived in America my entire life, and to me both A and B sound like they were obviously written by foreigners (A is a little better, though).

Comment: As written, this question is too broad to answer.  There are numerous errors with both sentences, and we don't allow "proofreading" questions that simply find and fix these errors.  Instead please word the question to include *specifics* of what you find confusing, and also include any research that shows what you *think* should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are wrong in several ways. Firstly, I'll explain the corrections that have been made from B to A.

The word "even" at the start doesn't need to be said. It doesn't add anything, and I'm not sure what it was there for in the first place.

Secondly, B uses "are the same meaning". This has been changed in A to "mean the same thing". This is a correct change. You could also say, "have the same meaning". This is why this correction has been made, because "are" is incorrect here.

There is then the problem that the first sentence doesn't make any sense in A or B. I am guessing at what you want to say, but try:

> We might think that the two words below mean the same thing.

"Can" is the wrong word. "Might" is correct here because "can think" means that you are able to think it. "Might" suggests it is possible to have this opinion, which is closer to what I think you mean.

I have also changed "sentences" to "words" because you are comparing "get" to "have". The second sentence should be:

> But, when I watch an action movie, I hear "get" a lot more than "have".

Using "I think" doesn't add anything. It's not a phrasing a native speaker would write. 
The third sentence:

> So, I think "get" has a more active or urgent meaning than "have".

I've just added "a" because are giving a specific meaning. You can say the phrase "it has meaning" as well, but you can't say that here because you specifically say "active or urgent".